# Composer package not found in any version

Tags: github, version-control, composer-php, packagist

I am trying to create a custom vendor package but have not yet put the package on packagist. According to the docs, the package can be loaded from git (vcs) instead of packagist: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

The yii2 project (although don't think framework matters) I have created package inside vendor folder:

foundationize/yii2-foundation
(folder structure is as above, I have quadruple-checked).

My root public_html/composer.json has following entries:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "foundationize/yii2-foundation": "dev-master" 
    },
```

My package composer file, vendor/foundationize/yii2-foundation/composer.json looks like:

```
{
    "name": "foundationize/yii2-foundation",
    "description": "The Foundation extension for the Yii2 framework",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "foundation"],
    "type": "yii2-extension",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/foundationize/yii2-foundation/issues",
        "wiki": "https://github.com/foundationize/yii2-foundation/wiki",
        "source": "https://github.com/foundationize/yii2-foundation.git"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "gvanto",
            "email": "gvanto@hotmail.com",
            "homepage": "http://foundationize.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "foundationize\\foundation\\": ""
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "packagist": false,
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/foundationize/yii2-foundation.git"           
        }
    ]       
}
```

When I run composer install (or update), I keep getting error below:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - The requested package foundationize/yii2-foundation could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Potential causes:
>
> - A typo in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>   https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion
>   for more details.
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for
> further common problems.

I have googled it high and low, read the docs can't seem to get it to work (always the same error, which I actually think would be more useful if it said either the package was not found OR the incorrect package version was found).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the `repositories` entry to your root `composer.json` file. Otherwise, Composer does not know where to search for your package.

Comment: Thanks xabbuh this seemed to work better ... thank you! What I don't get is how (if the repositories source is in the root composer.json) composer knows which package to get from the vcs source and which from packagist? I only want the one package (foundationize/yii2-foundation) to be found on github (custom source), not the other packages ..

Comment: Composer will only use other sources than Packagist for a package if you configured a repository that contains information about it and for which the version constraint is satisfied. So if you only add the GitHub repository for the `foundationize/yii2-foundation` package, all other packages will be loaded through Packagist.

Comment: "So if you only add the GitHub repository for the foundationize/yii2-foundation package" -> but i am not: I'm putting it in root - that's what I mean, since I'm specifying the 'repositories' field under the ROOT (not the package itself), how is this source tied/linked to this package? is it by name? Would have expected to be able to specify a (overridden if you will) source for a package in the package's composer.json file (not the root) ... sorry for confusion I don't think the composer docs are too clear about this

Comment: What I meant is that the GitHub repository that you added to your `composer.json` file is https://github.com/foundationize/yii2-foundation.git which only defines the `foundationize/yii2-foundation`. Composer will clone that repository, check its `composer.json` file and therefore will know that this package is located in that repository (because of the `name` key in the configuration).

Comment: OK seems like a slightly reversed way of doing things (wouldn't it be easier if I told composer where to find the source for this package directly instead?) but I'm sure there's a reason they doing it that way. Thanks xabbuh for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem to this and it was because I was running composer in the /web directory in the new Drupal structure. When I ran it in the root all was fine. Annoyingly, you need to run Drush in /web

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel version 5.5 there is a Package Auto-Discovery feature, so there is no need to add service provider. All you need to register package like this:

> composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar:dev-master

You can find more info in these articles:

https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/package-auto-discovery-in-laravel-5-5-ea9e3ab20518
https://divinglaravel.com/laravels-package-auto-discovery